# Image size not changing with different quality when compressed with CoreCompat

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-core, compression, jpeg

I would like to compress image to jpeg using CoreCompat library in ASP.NET Core 2. There is quality parameter that I would like to change and get images with different qualities and file sizes. Problem is that with different values for quality parameters, I get same file size. What am I doing wrong? For quality I was using values 0, 50 and 100. Here is my code:

```
const int size = 500;
const long quality = 50L;

string inputPath = @"D:\Images\land.jpg";
string outputPath = $@"D:\Images\land_{quality}.jpg";

using (var image = new Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(inputPath)))
{
    var resized = new Bitmap(size, size);
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(resized))
    {
        graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
        graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, size, size);
        using (var output = File.Open(outputPath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            var qualityParamId = Encoder.Quality;
            var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
            encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(qualityParamId, quality);
            var codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders()
                .FirstOrDefault(c => c.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid);
            resized.Save(output, codec, encoderParameters);
        }
    }
}
```

My input file lang.jpg has size 5MB (8386x2229) and output files land_0.jpg, land_50.jpg and land_100.jpg all have 62KB and dimensions 500x500. Why these output files have same size?

Answer (score 0):

The quality adjustment doesn't guarantee smaller file sizes, it only determines how "lossy" the compression is. However, ultimately a pixel is a pixel and there must be one or more bytes to encode that pixel and its color. The only guaranteed way to reduce file size is to reduce resolution, which means there's less pixels to encode and thus less bytes necessary to represent the image.

Image compression works in two ways. First, some attempt is made to reduce the overall bytes needed to encode the image. In types like GIF and PNG, this is done by limiting the colorspace. By limiting the image to a total of 256 colors, for example, instead of potentially millions, more pixels will share the same color and can therefore rely on the color index instead of a specific color. In the case of something like a JPEG, this is achieved by reducing the fine detail. The end result is largely the same: more pixels end up sharing the same colors, allowing better compression.

The second part of compression is achieved by using these shared pixel characteristics to reduce the overall bytes necessary to encode. Instead of each pixel having to include bytes to encode its particular color, you can just encode a single color and say this set of pixels uses that. It's the same way archives like zip work, in that it's using placeholders to share bytes that would otherwise have to be encoded individually.

The point of this is that compression ratios vary wildy and are 100% dependent on the image/data being compressed. In the case of an image, if there's a lot of colors and/or lots of fine detail, even turning the quality down to 0 may not actually achieve much. Some image information is discarded, but there's so much information to begin with that the end result is relatively insignificant. Again, 500x500 pixels is 500x500 pixels, regardless of the quality setting. Turning the quality down allows more aggressive compression, but depending on the source, even aggressive compression may not be able to remove many bytes.